# How to keep puppeteer browser running background without jumping to foreground on Windows?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I have an app  that opens the same website using puppetter by timer and checks some velues. Every time the page opened again it takes the focus. I want to run it on background and don't grab focus. I found some info how to do it on mac, by chaning Info.plist, but i can't find .local-chromium folder on Windows (this is the path from the answer regarding Mac node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/mac-XXXXXX/chrome-mac/Chromium.app/Contents/Info.plist). Can you help me please?

Answer (score 0):

Set the launch Options headless: "new" or true depending on your puppeteer version.
Example:

```
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you're looking for a way to keep Puppeteer running in the background without taking focus every time it opens a webpage on Windows. Unfortunately, the technique you've found is specific to MacOS where it tinkers with the Chromium application's property list file (Info.plist).

For Windows, there isn't an equivalent property list to modify. Puppeteer runs using Chromium, and Chromium inherently requests focus when it is launched.

One workaround for this issue could be to use Puppeteer in headless mode. When you launch Puppeteer, you can pass in `headless: true` to have the browser run in the background without a UI:

```js
const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
```

In headless mode, Chromium doesn't request focus and will run silently in the background, allowing your other applications to remain in focus.

However, if you need to run Puppeteer in a non-headless mode, another possible workaround is to run your code inside a virtual machine or Docker container, which won't steal focus from your main operating system.